# Personal Macro Not Looping in Different Workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

My problem is looping through several worksheets in a workbook.

I need to save the macro in my personal workbook, but if I do this, it loops through the same worksheet until it reaches the sheet count.

If I move the code to the current workbook, it works beautifully.  I have investigated writing a macro to copy the module from personal workbook to the current workbook, but for other users this module will simply be saved in another workbook that is only open in the background to run the module.

How do I get this to loop through all worksheets in another workbook, when the code is saved to a module in my personal workbook, or simply saved in another workbook that is open in the background?

Code below:

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

  ' Loop Through Worksheets, Add Totals

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet

  ' Loop Sum Formula Through All Worksheets

  For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
  ws.Activate

  'Now my code, the do something, (I have simplified this part since this _
   works, its the loop that's broken)

   'Insert new blank rows
  Rows("1:6").Select
  Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

   'Got to next worksheet, but it will not!
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Try changing For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets to For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.  If you want it to run in the workbook that the user has open and not in the workbook where the Macro is stored.

Comment: I still get the same problem.  It seems to recognize the current workbook and recognize the current worksheets as it loops 9 times, which is how many sheets are in the workbook, but it will not loop through each worksheet.

Comment: Have you tried running the macro from a brand new workbook to see if it's something specific to the one you want to use it on?

Comment: I have.  In fact, it's always a new workbook every time I download the new data.  Its first in CSV format, I tried it there, then saves as xlsx format with macros enables, still same issue.

Comment: I meant just opening a new workbook and not importing any data just to see if it loops through the 3 default sheets and end up on the Sheet3.  The reason I ask is because it can't be a coincidence that both Vinnie and myself are running the code and getting the expected result.  Neither of us have your data nor do we have any extra code, I wasn't making it do anything except activate each sheet to check that it was doing that on the correct workbook.  Sometimes when things aren't working you need to strip it back to basics and build it back up again.

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  I did just that after stepping back for a day.  I am new to coding, so I apologize for being a little slow on the topic.  I ended up getting it to work.  Just made the adjustments both you and Vinnie recommended.  I swear I tried this before and after you both recommended it, but something tells me I missed it somewhere.  I'm clueless as to what I REALLY did wrong, but I updated the code to show the working code.  THanks again for all your help, greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code has a bit different logic, but try it if it works:

```
   Sub WorksheetLoop()

      ' Loop Through Worksheets, Add Totals

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
    Dim path As String
    Dim WorkingFile As Workbook
      ' Select the file you will manipulate to surely be in the correct WB.
    path = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.*), *.*", Title:="Please select a file you want to modify")
    Workbooks.Open path
    Set WorkingFile = ActiveWorkbook

      For Each ws In WorkingFile.Worksheets
      ws.Rows("1:6").Insert Shift:=xlDown

      'Rest of the code
      Next
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Vinnie, still no luck.  I actually started by using "ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets", but still not success.  It recognizes the number of open sheets, and runs that many times, but never changes the sheet it is on and runs on the same worksheet over and over again until it reaches the sheet count.  I am going bonkers trying to get it to loop properly, without having to implement the code directly to the active workbook.

Comment: Try `debug.print ws.name` in the immeadiate window to check which sheet is active.

Comment: Ok, I got this debug to show which worksheet it is in.  I wasn't looking in the right place.  Weird thing is, it is cycling through the loop in the same worksheet, but the debug registers the different worksheet names as if it thinks its in different worksheets.  How or why does this happen and how can i get it to actually loop through each one and not just think it is?

Comment: Additionally, if move the module from my personal workbook to the actual workbook, it registers the worksheet names in order, regardless of which worksheet is actually selected.  Still, it actually goes through each worksheet appropriately.

Comment: Hi Vinnie,  Unfortunately, still unsuccessful!  I am about to throw my hands up and say forget it.  I honestly don't know what I am doing wrong, and every solution offered just produces the same result.  I am at a loss here.  I appreciate all the help you've provided.  If i ever find a solution I'll be sure to update here.  I bet it will be something super easy!

Comment: Somehow, It works now!  Made the change you and Gordon recommended.  Changed ThisWorkbook to ActiveWorkbook, and that did it!  What is making me go mad as I know I tried this before and after your suggestion, but I cant tell if I missed the code somewhere else?  Added updated code to show the working code.  Thanks again!  Also, how do i get the code names in my reply to grey out so you know I'm indicating code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code, Now to compare it to what was originally posted code.

Thanks again Vinnie and Gordon!

```
Sub Step_3_Add_Subtotals()

' Loop Through Worksheets, Add Totals

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet

' Loop Sum Formula Through All Worksheets


For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Activate

  'Now my code, the do something

'Insert new blank rows

Rows("1:6").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

'Copy current headers, paste them in K3:Q3
Range("K7:Q7").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("K3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste


'Got to next worksheet, and now it does!

Next

starting_ws.Activate

End Sub
```